# On Android ICS multiple choice is broken in one of my ListViews

Tags: android, android-listview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My android flash cards app has a bug that only occurs in ICS. The checkboxes behave like radiobuttons, like it was single-choice.

```
public class CardSetListActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.card_set_list);

        ListAdapter adapter = getSimpleCursorAdapter();
        // ListAdapter adapter = getArrayAdapter();

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    }

    private ListAdapter getSimpleCursorAdapter() {
        CardsDbAdapter dbAdapter = CardsDbAdapter.getInstance(this);
        Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.fetchAllCardSets();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        String[] fromColumns = new String[] { CardsDbAdapter.COL_CARD_SET };
        int[] toResources = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
        return new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, cursor, fromColumns, toResources);
    }

    private ListAdapter getArrayAdapter() {
        String[] GENRES = new String[] { "Action", "Adventure", "Animation" };
        return new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, GENRES);
    }
}
```

Any idea where I could look for a solution?
With the SimpleCursorAdapter, the Checkboxes behave like RadioButtons. With the ArrayAdapter they behave right.
I'm changing to use ArrayAdapter now but would still like to know what's going on here.

Comment: It doesn't throw errors. It simply does not allow to set more than one check box. The check boxes look correct but behave like radio buttons.

Comment: I had the same problem and only on Android 4.0.x. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12012029/1018177) solved it for me.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Just checked my version history and found: "2012-05-24 01:43 - converted the SimpleCurserAdapter in CardSetListActivity to an ArrayAdapter to fix the multiple-choice-bug in API 15"